# Windows 10 - 1709 upgrade breaks default mail associations

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

I noticed on a number of our machines since the 1709 upgrade that using the "Share by email" in an office (2013) application or sending a mail using the snipping tool is broken. The error that pops up is general mail failure or soomething along the lines.

I found a so called fix to the problem which is mentioned in this post here [Since Win 10 1709 upgrade, Snipping tool 'Send Snip' does not work](https://superuser.com/questions/1266164/since-win-10-1709-upgrade-snipping-tool-send-snip-does-not-work)

We're in an environment with a few hundred users so repairing office isn't really a fix since it effects a large amount of PC's.

My guess is either something wasn't migrated in the upgrade or the mail app coming back breaks something.

Has anyone found a better solution ?

Comment: Asking for a *better* solution makes your question too subjective for this Q&A site. Instead, consider asking how to solve this problem in an environment with many users. From there, answers can be voted up/down based on their effectiveness in such an environment. (That said, this question belongs on Server Fault, but this issue of subjectivity needs to be fixed before it can be migrated.)

Answer (score 0):

> I found a so called fix to the problem which is mentioned in this post here Since Win 10 1709 upgrade, Snipping tool 'Send Snip' does not work
>
> We're in an environment with a few hundred users so repairing office isn't really a fix since it effects a large amount of PC's.

Is there no way to write a script that does this and then mass deploy it to the network? I'm no programmer so I can't help on that front unfortunately. If you have any sort of developer on site maybe you could ask them for help?

Other than that, maybe you could contact the Microsoft support team directly as they probably know a lot more about their own programs than anyone here.